# Azure ML in "Execute Python Script" module :Common table expressions is not supported in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, common-table-expression, azure-machine-learning-service, cortana-intelligence

I ran into this issue yesterday, while trying to use the same sqlite script I used in "Apply SQL Transformation" module in Azure ML, in Sqlite over Python module in Azure ML:

```
with tbl as (select * from t1)
select * from tbl
```

Here is the error I got:

```
[Critical]     Error: Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 169, in batch
data:text/plain,Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
    odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 388, in read_sql
  File "C:\temp\azuremod.py", line 193, in azureml_main
    results = pd.read_sql(query,con)
    coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1017, in execute
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1022, in read_sql
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1006, in execute
---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ----------
    cur.execute(*args)
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql:  with tbl as (select * from t1)
                    select * from tbl
```

and the Python code:

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlite3 as lite
    import sys
    con = lite.connect('data1.db')
    con.text_factory = str
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        if (dataframe1 is not None):
            cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1")
            dataframe1.to_sql('t1',con)
        query = '''with tbl as (select * from t1)
                    select * from tbl'''                      
        results = pd.read_sql(query,con)    

    return results,
```

when replacing the query with:

```
select * from t1
```

It worked as expected.
As you probably know, Common table expressions is a key feature in Sqlite, the ability to run recursive code is a "must have" in any functional language such as Sqlite.

I also tried to run my Python script in Jupyter Notebook in Azure, that also worked as expected.

Is it possible we have a different configuration for Sqlite in the Python module than in Jupyter Notebook and in "Apply SQL Transformation" module?

Comment: Cheap none answer is to try and add the specific version of sqllite3 that you would like, here is a guide. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreasderuiter/archive/2015/02/16/azure-ml-now-apparently-supports-executing-python-scripts.aspx but I also don't actually see sqllite3 on that list... It is very possible that the notebook and module package versions are not in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and reviewed the `SQL Queries` doc of `pandas.io.sql` at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries. I tried to use `read_sql_query` to solve it, but failed.

According to the `pandas` doc, tt seems that `Pandas` not support the usage for this SQL syntax.

Base on my experience and according to your SQL, I tried to do the SQL `select * from (select * from t1) as tbl` instead of your SQL that work for `Pandas`.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.